# Connect spyder to a remote kernel via ssh tunnel

Tags: spyder, remote-server, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect spyder, running on local_machine (macOS), to a remote kernel running on compute_server (a compute node of a cluster). The compute node is not directly accessible via the internet, I can only access the cluster via login_server.

I try the following:

1. On compute_server I do:

   > python -m spyder_kernels.console

To connect another client to this kernel, use:
    --existing kernel-20351.json

I copy this json file to the appropriate place on local_machine. It contains the text:
 "shell_port": 46540,
  "iopub_port": 39268,
  "stdin_port": 40704,
  "control_port": 42637,
  "hb_port": 46887,

2. I create an ssh tunnel through login_server. On local_machine I do:

ssh -L46540:compute_server:46540 -L39268:compute_server:39268 -L40704:compute_server:40704 -L42637:compute_server:42637 -L46887:compute_server:46887 me@login_server

3. I start spyder on local_machine, ask it to connect to an existing kernel, enter the name of the json file, check the 'This is a remote kernel' box, enter me@login_server for Host name. I have ssh keys set up for login to login_server already.

The connection hangs. If I start the spyder kernel on login_server and omit Step 2 then it works fine, but I can't do heavy computation on login_server, I do have to work on compute_server.

Any ideas?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please omit step 2. in your description above and try again. You don't need to create a tunnel by hand because Spyder does that for you (that's why it needs your ssh credentials).

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work if I start the kernel on a compute node. If I put me@compute_server in the dialogue box for Host name then it doesn't connect (presumably because I am not able to ssh into compute_server). If I put me@login_server it doesn't work either, presumably because spyder has no idea which of the several thousand compute nodes in the cluster the kernel is running. The json file does not seem to have this information. As stated in my original post, omitting step 2 works fine if I start the kernel on a login node, but not if I start it on a compute node.

Comment: could you solve this issue? I'm having the same problem and I can't find a workaround

Comment: No I never solved it but I did find that it is possible to do the same thing for Jupyter. I used a set of tools written specifically for the cluster on which I was working, but if you have the time you may be able to adapt something for Spyder. https://github.com/Kirill888/nci-tools Please let me know if you have any success.

Comment: @JulianGiles, if you're still looking, entering `localhost` as the Hostname when connecting Spyder to the remote kernel (and entering the correct port), should work, I believe.

Comment: @LuKas yes, I am sorry I never confirmed here if I had any success. Indeed you need to connect entering localhost as the Hostname, since the tunnel is linking your local port to the remote server

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should work if you connect Spyder to your `localhost`. So at the 'This is a remote kernel' box, enter `localhost` for the Host name. And enter the relevant port(!).

(And add your username and password for `compute_server`.)