# Spyder -- Connect to remote kernel via proxy

Tags: ssh, ipython, jupyter, spyder, remote-server

I'm trying to connect to a remote kernel in Spyder, however the machine on which it is running is not directly accessible. Rather, to connect to it I must go through a [bastion host](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-proxy-bastion-proxyjump) / [jumpbox](https://starkandwayne.com/blog/jumping-seamlessly-thorough-tunnels-a-guide-to-ssh-proxy/) as follows:
`ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -J me@jumpbox me@remote` which logs me directly into `remote`, automatically sending the connection through `jumpbox`.

I have `python -m spyder-kernels.console` [running](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/panes/ipythonconsole.html?highlight=remote#connect-to-a-remote-kernel) on `remote`, where I want to do my computing, but no way to connect to it directly since it's only accessible from `jumpbox`. I've tried setting up my ssh config with a `ProxyJump` entry which works for logging into the machine through ssh in the command line, but it appears that Spyder ignores the config file when setting up the remote kernel connection,

Is there a way to connect to this remote kernel? It appears there's [a way](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Cookbook:-Connecting-to-a-remote-kernel-via-ssh) to do this with IPython and I know I can do it with Jupyter Notebook, but I'm wondering if I can do this in Spyder.

(Related: [Connect spyder to a remote kernel via ssh tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56351382/connect-spyder-to-a-remote-kernel-via-ssh-tunnel))

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) How do you connect to that kernel using Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0):

*I don't know if you're still looking for an answer to this, but for future people arriving here, and for my own reference:*

Yes, you can. You have to **create an ssh-tunnel and connect Spyder to the kernel via localhost**. For you that would look something like this:

```
ssh -L 3336:me@jumpbox:22 me@remote
```

`22` is for the port your ssh server at remote is listening to. This is usually 22, unless the moderator changed this. `3336` is the port at localhost to connect to, you can choose any number you like above 1024 (which are privileged ports).

---

Then **proceed as explained in the [Spyder docs](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/panes/ipythonconsole.html#connect-to-a-remote-kernel)**, i.e., launch the spider kernel (in the environment you want) on  `remote`

```
python -m spyder_kernels.console
```

copy the connection file (`kernel-pid.json`) file to your local computer:

```
scp -oProxyJump=me@jumpbox remote:/path/to/json-file/kernel-pid.json ~/Desktop
```

`/path/to/json-file` you have to change to the path to the connection file (which you can find by running `jupyter --runtime-dir` on `remote` in the same environment as the spyder-kernel is running) and `kernel-pid.json` of course to the real file name. `~/Desktop` copies it to your Desktop-folder, you can change that to wherever you want.

---

**Connect Spyder to the kernel** via "Connect to existing kernel", point it to the connection file you just copied, check the This is a remote kernel (via SSH) box and **enter `localhost` as the Hostname**, and `3336` as the port (or whichever port you changed it to).

**That should do it.**

---

**Note**, that, as is the case for me, your `jumpbox` server may break your ssh connection over which you launched the Spyder kernel, which will cause your kernel to break. So you might want to use

```
python -m spyder_kernels.console &
```

to have it run in the background, or launch it in a `screen` session. However, note that you cannot shutdown a remote kernel with exit, and it will keep running (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059606/shutting-down-a-remote-kernel-from-spyder)), so you have to kill it in a different way.